# How to create object attributes from dictionary key/values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an excel file that contains some required parameters and their values and I am trying to feed them into the `__init__` function of my class entity. I know the below must be setting `self.key` to each value in turn, but should I be "masking"(?) the `.key`?:

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self):
        for key, value in zip(excelDF.attribs, excelDF.values):
            if key!=None and value !=None:
                self.key= value
```

To give an example of what I am trying for:

```
excelDF.attribs=['name','telephone']
excelDF.values=['Tom','01234-567890']
customer1=Customer()
print(customer1.name)
print(customer1.telephone)
```

gives...

```
Tom
01234-567890
```

Comment: Use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)

Comment: @deepspace answer below is great, small remark for this code: don't use `=` and `!=` for singleton objects like `None`, use `is` if you need such check for some reason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self):
        for key, value in zip(excelDF.attribs, excelDF.values):
            if key is not None and value is not None:
                setattr(self, key, value)
```

If a key happens to be an invalid Python identifier it will only be accessible with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#getattr).

Usage example:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3]

class Customer:
    def __init__(self):
        for key, value in zip(keys, values):
            if key is not None and value is not None:
                setattr(self, key, value)

cust = Customer()
print(cust.a, cust.b, cust.c)
# 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another less conventional approach using type to define the class:

```
Customer = type("Customer",
                (),
                dict(zip(excelDF.attribs, excelDF.values)))
```

ref: http://python-course.eu/python3_classes_and_type.php

Comment: Correct, but this will get very messy if OP wants to define some methods in `Customer` class.

Answer (score 0):

I want to present 2 alternatives:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


class Customer:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.get("name")
        self.number = kwargs.get("number")


class Customer2:
    name = ""
    number = ""

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        o = cls()
        for k in [k for k in vars(cls) if not k.startswith("_")]:
            setattr(o, k, d.get(k))
        return o


keys = ["name", "number", "bla"]
values = ["John", "00109563221", "Blub"]

data = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}
c1 = Customer(**data)
c2 = Customer2.from_dict(data)

print(c1.name)
print(c2.number)
```

Here the stress lies on the constructor *pulling* in what it needs of the data instead of taking all that comes along.

Cave: Solution2 relies on the fact, that you only want dumb data objects, where the only fields you are interested in are defined class variables.